# Twitter API v2 Streaming with Retrofit or OkHttp

Tags: twitter, retrofit2, okhttp, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying integrate the new Twitter API specifically the [streaming](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/9956214/T1LMiT5U?version=latest#da00dd80-4d2c-4dd2-8b4f-9b6ce8bb6bcd) tweets part in my android app, I am using Retrofit for my http calls.

When I try to make the call to get the streaming tweets it just hangs and does not return anything.

this is my retrofit call

```
@Streaming
@GET("tweets/search/stream")
suspend fun getFilteredStream(@Header("Authorization") token:String)
```

I then tried making a call with just OkHttp as shown in the documentation I get a successful response but I dont know how to stream the data.

I can make the call successfully via a curl call and see the data no problem.

How do I stream the data via retrofit or OkHttp

**Update:**

With OkHttp I was able to get data by doing this

```
val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .build()
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream")
            .method("GET", null)
            .build()
        val response: Response = client.newCall(request).execute()
        val source = response.body?.source()
        val buffer = Buffer()
        while(!source!!.exhausted()){
            response.body?.source()?.read(buffer, 8192)
            val data = buffer.readString(Charset.defaultCharset())
        }
```

`data` holds the string data representation of multiple tweet objects but how do I read one tweet at a time, or parse the response like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, I think you'll need to combine the two examples you have.

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/108fe23964b986107aed352ba467cd2007d15208/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/http/Streaming.java

> Treat the response body on methods returning {@link ResponseBody ResponseBody} as is, i.e. without converting the body to {@code byte[]}.

And example calling code

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/108fe23964b986107aed352ba467cd2007d15208/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit2/CallTest.java#L599

I suspect, dependending on the JSON API you use you may be able to use a Streaming API from the response body.  But if not you could split on either just newline or newline followed by { on next line and parse individually.  Sorry I can't help here.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Concatenated_JSON

Comment: Using `ResponseBody` for the retrofit call worked, I then split the string on `\r\n` and it seems to work, I just worry about how reliable its going to be parsing it like that

Comment: It should be reasonably, you can change to using a real JSON parser for this, if you see examples from wikipedia it should be clear that as long as it's line split it will keep working.

Comment: @tyczj can you please post your solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @tyczj does your solution with `ResponseBody` give you every message when it arrives, or does it give you one chunk?